# Why is it saying 'Invalid Object Name - Film?'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a FilmsController in a .Net application I am building, that prints out a list of films to appear on a page.

This uses an Index function from an automatically generated scaffolded controller, FilmsController.cs.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using MvcFilm.Data;
    using MvcFilm.Models;
    
    namespace MvcFilm.Controllers
    {
        public class FilmsController : Controller
        {
            private readonly MvcFilmContext _context;
    
            public FilmsController(MvcFilmContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
    
            // GET: Films
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {
                return View(await _context.Film.ToListAsync());
            }
```

However, when I click the link to visit the home page of the app that is supposed to call the index function and display a list of films, I get the following error message: "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid object name 'Film'".

I don't suppose anyone has an idea as to why this error might be occuring?

I have the following class in my "Models" folder:

```
namespace MvcFilm.Models
{
    public class Film { 
    
        // id field required by the database for the primary key
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)] // specifies the type of data (Date).
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        // The user not required to enter time information in the date field
        // Only the date is displayed, not time information.
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This should surely be able to create the object, no?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: your db is updated? remember to run your ef migrations: dotnet ef migrations add my-stuff, then dotnet ef database update

Comment: Try updating your DB context using `scaffold-dbcontext` . mostly that table is either removed or renamed

Comment: Have you added migrations yet?? If you just created the model and the DbContext, that is not enough.

Comment: @alessandro - cheers. I had run the migrations but there might have been an error somewhere so I deleted them and ran them again and the link seems to work this time - thanks!